System of Equations (With Calculus) For A Video Game
I'm implementing a feature in my video game where the player can adjust their lantern for visibility. They can adjust the angle/depth of the lantern by using the scroll-wheel of the mouse. When the angle ($\theta$) is smallest, the depth ($r$) is far, so the player gets a bright illumination of a small arc in front of them. When the angle is biggest, the depth is short, so they can see a broad arc, but only a few feet in front of them.
I feel like the easiest option is keeping the sector area ($A=\frac{r^2\theta}{2}$) of the light constant ($\frac{dA}{d\theta}=0=\frac{dA}{dr}$) and varying the depth and angle together "covariantly" (Am I using that word correctly?).
How do I best go about coming up with a system of equations that changes both $\theta$ and $r$ based on the input from the mouse wheel (let's call it $dm$)?

If I understand you correctly, you wish to keep the area of the lantern light $A(θ,r)$ constant, such that both $θ$ and $r$ are functions of m, correct? Well two things: 1, you don't need to do it this way, since the game engine probably runs on some $Δt$, you can compute the corresponding change $Δr$ for the change $Δθ$, by using some variable as your 'mouse scroll wheel' every  $Δt$ time.
So for example, consider setting $A(θ,r)=50$. Then if we scroll the mouse wheel up (corresponding to increasing $m$ to $m_{\text{new}}$) then all you have to do is solve for $$r_{\text{new}}= \sqrt{\frac{100}{\theta(m_\text{new})}}$$ to get the new radius and vice versa for $θ$. However, this works as long as only one variable changes, $\Delta t$ is small enough and this calculation can be done fast enough.
2, if you want or have to do it this way, note that if $A = \frac{\theta(m) r^2(m)}{2}$, then $$\frac{dA}{d\theta} = \frac{\frac{dA}{dm}}{\frac{d \theta}{dm}} = \frac{\frac{\frac{d \theta}{dm}r^2(m) + 2r(m)\theta(m)\frac{dr}{dm}}{2}}{\frac{d \theta}{dm}} = 0$$ which tells us that $$\frac{d \theta}{dm}r^2(m) + 2r(m)\theta(m)\frac{dr}{dm} = 0$$
Doing this calculation for $\frac{dA}{dr} =0$ gives you the same result, and you can't simplify the above if you don't know one of the functions.
Side note- if you already know both functions, you can actually compute $\frac{d \theta}{dr}$, but I am not sure if it's useful for your problem

Beautiful! A practical, fast version for the game, and additionally the "total derivative" mathematically pure version that I was hoping for as a mathematician! Thank you!

Happy to help! I like seeing maths implemented in more modern media like video games, and it's always fun to work then out
